# Can I divide the standard deviation of two samples to create an overall standard deviation?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I calculate a project's change order rate by dividing the cost increase by the awarded value.  For example, if the awarded value is 10,000 and there is a cost increase of 200, the change order rate would be 2% (200 / 10,000).  The **overall** change order rate of a sample would be the sum of cost increases from all projects divided by the sum of awarded values for all projects (sum of all cost increases / sum of all awarded values).

My question: I want to calculate the overall standard deviation of change order rates.  Can I divide the SD of the cost increases by the SD of all awarded values (SD cost increases / SD awarded value) and report this as the standard deviation of change order rates?

See example:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can check it yourself. For example, the standard deviation of change order rate (2%, 21%, 33%, 5%) is 14.5%, which is different from your 56%.

In other words, your question is whether the standard deviation of a ratio distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) equals the ratio of standard deviations of the two distributions. The answer is no. Even the mean of a ration is not equal to the ratio of mean values of the two distributions. Actually, the analytical solution to the standard deviation of a ratio distribution is quite complex. For example, the ratio of two normals with mean zero is Cauchy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), while the mean and variance of Cauchy is undefined. In most cases (including your case), people can just numerically calculate standard deviation of a ratio distribution (the change order rate in your case).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  How then would I numerically calculate the standard deviation of the change order rate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but I think the standard deviation of the change order rate is STDEV(C2:C5), which is answered in the first paragraph.